# When Using JSQMessagesViewController the UI does not appear

Tags: ios, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to implement JSQMessagesViewController, and I am following the  Ray Wenderlich tutorial(https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat), but the UI is not appearing on my view controller, it is just blank.
This is my pod file.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
target "Sell Goods" do
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
    pod 'Google/SignIn'
    pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
end
```

I have tried using a bridging header but that did not work, and I followed the tutorial step by step.

Segue to ChatViewController

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let editingVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ChatsViewController
        else {
            preconditionFailure("Bad")
        }
    editingVC.senderId = userID
    editingVC.senderDisplayName = userName
}
```

ChatViewController

```
import Firebase
import JSQMessagesViewController

class ChatsViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
var outgoingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
var incomingBubbleImageView: JSQMessagesBubbleImage!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    title = "ChatChat"
    setupBubbles()
    //collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero
    //collectionView!.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    resetScreen = true
}
private func setupBubbles() {
    let factory = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    outgoingBubbleImageView = factory.outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(
        UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleBlueColor())
    incomingBubbleImageView = factory.incomingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor(
        UIColor.jsq_messageBubbleLightGrayColor())
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                             messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.senderId == senderId {
        return outgoingBubbleImageView
    } else {
        return incomingBubbleImageView
    }
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                             messageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}
override func collectionView(collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!,
                             avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return nil
}

}
```

Comment: We can't guess what is going on by just showing us your pod-file. We need more info.

Comment: You need to call `super.viewDidLoad` and `super.viewDidAppear`

Comment: Wow, that was simple, thank you

Comment: You do not need a `BridgingHeader` in order to accomplish this.

Comment: where is your `setupBubbles()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `super.viewDidLoad` & `super.viewDidDisappear`